# Get 2 unique numbers in a row?

Tags: c++

I want to make sure 'grid' can't return 2 same values, but I'm not sure how. Here's my code:

`grid[rnd(2,x-2) * y + rnd(2,y-2)].height = rnd(25,40);`

```
int rnd(int min, int max) {
    return min + rand() % (max - min + 1);
}
```

I also seeded rand() with `srand(time(NULL));`

I wish I could provide more details or what I tried, but I couldn't quite find anything related to this topic.

EDIT: I could of course do re-randoming, but I feel like it's bad practice :/

Comment: (Pseudo-)randomness is orthogonal with uniqueness.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you really need to avoid consecutive repeats,<sup>1</sup> all you need to do is pass the previous value into your function, and then generate random numbers in a loop until it is distinct.

Pseudo-code:

```
int rnd(..., int prev) {
    int y;
    do {
        y = rand() ...;
    } while (y == prev);
    return y;
}
```

Note that you could alternatively maintain `prev` as a static variable inside the function.  But this would render it incapable of generating multiple independent streams simultaneously.

---

<sub>1. Which actually makes things less "random", in the sense of becoming more predictable.</sub>

Comment: or shuffle a unique list and pick random values from the list.

Comment: @KillianDS: Indeed.  Although I get the impression that the OP simply wants to avoid *consecutive* duplicates, so a Fisher-Yates-like approach might be overkill here.